# Directions in a binary search tree

Tags: java, insert, binary-search-tree

I am trying to complete a code that will insert a node in a binary tree by following the directions "L", "R", "F" or "M", to determine where the node will be. I only need to complete the directions part of the code after the for loop.

I'm guessing the best way to implement this will be using if statements.

/* Insert a node in a binary tree, given directions to reach the parent node of the 
     * data to insert. We use directions to find where in the tree to "plug" the node
     * TODO 5. Complete the implementation of this method.
     * Example: directions may be "LLRL": 
     * The first (n-1) characters (assuming directions has n characters) indicate how to navigate (Left, 
     * Right, Father, Mother) from the root to the node after which insertion will occur.
     * The last character of directions indicate whether to insert as left node or right node (or as father line
     * or mother line).
     * Most of the code is given to you below, but look for "TODO 5" for indication of where to complete the code.

```
public void insertDataAtLocation(String directions, T data) { 
    // if directions = "0", it means that the data to insert will be the root
    if (directions.equals("0")) {
        root = new BTNode<T>(data);
        return;
    }

    // if the data to insert was not the root, we need to traverse the tree so as to
    // find the location where to insert it.
    // We create an iterator, just like we do for singly linked lists
    BTNode<T> iter = root;
    // And now we follow directions:
    for (int j = 0; j < directions.length() - 1; j++) {
         if(directions.charAt(directions.length()) == 'L'){

        }
        if(directions.charAt(directions.length()) == 'R'){

        }

    }   
    // Let's build the node to be plugged
    BTNode<T> N = new BTNode<T>(data);
    // Now we "plug" / insert the new node in the proper side (left or right) 
    // depending on the last character of directions    
    if (directions.charAt(directions.length()-1) == 'L' || directions.charAt(directions.length()-1) == 'F') {
        iter.setLeft(N);   
    }
    if (directions.charAt(directions.length()-1) == 'R' || directions.charAt(directions.length()-1) == 'M') {
        iter.setRight(N);   
    }
}
```

Comment: `// code to finish` I think this part needs a little more work from you.

Comment: I updated the code, know I just need to figure out how to set the node left or right